# New domain marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mydomain, deliverability

Hello everyone we just purchased marketing cloud , we were asked to buy a new domain for it so that our current one does get blacklisted ( ps: we couldn"t get a sub-domain of our current domain),  however the one we bought does match our branding perfectly. Is it possible to start with this new one and then change it later on to the one of our Brand ( we are using it now for Pardot) ? or once it is associated with Marketing Cloud SAP, it cannot be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will normally suggest a sub-domain: *email.example.com*
If “email” is already taken, use “em” (for email) or “cp” for campaign or similar. Example: *em.example.com* - It can be anything, but don’t use “sfmc” or “exacttarget” – don’t brand as Salesforce, it defeats the purpose of branding.

However, since you can't use a subdomain, we need to look at alternatives. But this might introduce some [challenges with so-called cousin domains](https://www.agari.com/email-security-blog/dont-let-your-customers-be-fooled-by-cousin-domains/). So don't go with *example-email.com* as it might give a perception of phishing/spoofing. Hence - do put pressure on whoever is managing your domains, and insist on a subdomain to your "main" branded domain.

You will be able to change your SAP domain later, but this will probably have a similar cost as if you were to buy a new SAP domain. Also, as the sender reputation is seen as a combination of your domain and IP address, you might be facing some deterioration of your sender reputation. I provide some advice on how to monitor your sender reputation in [my article on LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/email-deliverability-ip-warmup-lukas-lunow/). So a new round of IP warmup might be needed.

My advice will be to leave the domain you are using with Pardot alone, and start with a fresh subdomain as your SAP domain.

Comment: The issue here is that if we set up a new domain, is that once  we start sending out emails from marketing cloud, we don"t want that clients receive emails from this new domain then the reply email will be the one of our current domain and on the same time we cannot change the emails addresses of the whole company. So either we take the current domain and take the risk in marketing cloud because the whole purpose of getting a new domain is that we don"t get flagged or get the new one but it won"t represent our branding

Comment: You can configure Reply Mail Management to forward emails from the SAP domain to an email address on your regular domain, if needed

Comment: Yes lukas. However, we don"t want clients to receive e-mails from an e-mail address and get the answer from a different one. We were thinking to maybe set up MKG cloud with this new domain and then change it later. But 1. we don"t know if it is possible to change it? and even if it possible to change it i think that we will need to do IP warming again and start all over again

Comment: As I write in my question above, you will be able to change the domain at a later time, but there is a minor risk of reduced sender reputation